# How to use a variable which is declared in one class to another class in C#

Tags: c#

```
class employee
{
    int id;
    String name;
    int salary;
}

class employeeManager
{
   public void ExceptInputOutput()
    { 
    }
}
```

I have declared the variable in employee class & want to use that variable to the method `ExceptInputOutput()` of `employeeManager` class where both of the class are not main class. Main class will call the method of `employeeManager` class.  Now how can I use the variable `id`, `name` & `salary` to `ExceptInputOutput()` method.

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda inheritance maybe an approach OP should take. On other hand based on class names  -  "employee" and its "manager" is generally parent-child relation not "is-a" relation (indeed "manager" may be "employee" too, but doesn't have to).

Comment: nahida, Accessing member of other class covered in many SO questions - it is really good idea to search for existing posts first. If your question is actually about something else - you'd be better off asking new one (possibly linking to this).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You are correct. However the requirement is not clear enough as ther is more than one way available to do that including inheritace, making employee static, or by parameter passing any one of the 3 can solve the propose pbased on the context

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i have checked the existing post ... but that existing post dosen't give me any clear idea about that. Actually i am  nobish in C# so don't know how to use inheritance.. Now i know how to use inheritance in C#..

Comment: @user2946329 .... yes i checked your answer & it works... & i learn how to implement inheritance...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you inject the employee inside the employeeManager class?

```
public class employee
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public int salary { get; set; }
}

class employeeManager
{
   public void ExceptInputOutput(employee model)
   { 
       // model.id
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks Thiago Custodio.. Actually I want to seperate the method from variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The variables you have declaed in `employee` have two usage notes:

C# assumes an access modifier of [`private`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx) when none is specified (for class members) - you thus need to explicitly make those variables [`public`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx) to use them from another class.

In addition, the varuables are not [`static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) and thus are part of an instance of `emplaoyee` - you need to have an `employee` object to get values from. This can be declared `new` in `ExceptInputOutput()`, passed as a parameter, or declared a field in `employeeManager`.

Answer (score 0):

By using [`inheritance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) Like this:

```
public class employee
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public int Salary {get;set;}
}

public class employeeManager : employee
{
   public void ExceptInputOutput()
   { 
       //ID,Name,Salary are accessible
   }
}
```